# Android develop sign in and sign up in the same activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I saw many login samples(for example android studio login activity, firebase auth quickstart sample) that the sign in and the sign up buttons are in the same activity.
so they use the same fields.
and i am wondering if it is clear that when you click the sign up button you create a new account with the email and password you entered above.
link to a screenshot from my login activity
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7tBD.jpg

Comment: In my experience, the "sign up" button in one of these forms would take you to additional form entry - at the very least, a "confirm password" step.

Comment: bad design to have one form with two buttons that have different verbs. if anything, have the login button....then a textview at the bottom that says not register? register here. when clicked, it takes them to a new activity/fragment

Comment: in one activity do a sign up page, after signing up => go to login page=> then go to home page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, it is not clear.**

It's recommended to take the user to a new screen (launch a new Activity/Fragment) upon the click on the "Sign Up" button. Also, it's advised that you have 2 fields for password setting in case the person misspells the password upon sign up (this might cause the user to be unable to sign in).

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you to make that clear. If you accidentally try to sign in the user when they click the register button, then you will have an error. However, if you implement the `OnClickListeners` for each button correctly ( `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)` for signing in and `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)` for registering), then it will be clear as to what you are trying to do.